# Dynamic programming: Counting super numbers in between

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given two numbers, let's call them `X`  and `Y`  how to find all "super" numbers between them.

> A super number is a number whose neighbouring digits have an absolute
>   difference more than 1. So, for example, number 132 is not a super number 
>   because
>   3 and 2 have a difference equal to 1. Number 62 is a super number because 
>   diffrence between 6 and 2 is greather than 1.

How to find all super numbers between X and Y (included) using Dynamic programming?

```
1 < X,Y < 10^5000
```

Comment: I strongly recommend making a credible attempt and asking questions based on that attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a technique called Digit DP", or "Dp on digit". Let's imagine that we have a function f(x) tells the number of integers between 0 to x (inclusively) which are super digits, if you want to compute the number of super numbers between X, Y you only need calculate f(Y) and f(X-1), because the number of super numbers between X and Y is equal to f(Y)-f(X-1) (it's intuitive to notice why).

Then how should the function f (x) be? you need three states: 
index: the index on the string (the number) what are you processing.
tight: this will tell if the current digits range is restricted or not.

For example if you have the number:

1234 you can reach the states, 0234, 0000, 1231, etc. (numbers less or equal to 1234)

But you can't reach: 2234, 1244, etc.

The tight deals with controlling this.

last: the last used digit, this will help you with the transitions, for example if your last used digit is 4 your next digit can be 0, 1, 2 or 6, 7, 8, 9 (these only if the tight is not active).

I leave you a tutorial and places where you can find more information:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/digit-dp-introduction/ here you can understand better about the idea, and the tight use.
You also cand find information on competitive programming pages like codeforces, topcoder, codechef.

I usually see these problems in competitive programming, is this a problem for some judge? I would like to try a solution. . if that's the case, I really hope you're not in a live contest.